# mysql % due to spaces in db filepath

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql

why doesnt mysql deal with spaces and how do I combat it?

if i have a path name in the db with spaces it puts a % in place of the space which then isnt functional?

```
public partial class UserProfile : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite; User=root; Password=commando;");
        cn.Open();

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT User.FirstName, User.SecondName, User.Aboutme, User.DOB, Pictures.picturepath FROM User LEFT JOIN Pictures ON User.UserID = Pictures.UserID WHERE User.UserID=1", cn);
        OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Name.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1));
            Aboutme.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(2));
            Age.Text = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(3));
            Image1.ImageUrl = String.Format("{0}", reader.GetString(4));
        }


    }
}
```

output:

```
<div class="image">
                                                <a href="#"></a>
                                                <img style="border-width: 0px;" src="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample%20Pictures" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Image1">
                                                &nbsp;</div>
```

character set in mysql is latin 1 and swedish something or other unsure how to find it again?

Comment: are you sure it's MySQL that's placing the `%` in your strings and not some preprocessing function that's encoding the string first?

Comment: well i cant be sure on that but doesnt happen with any other db?

Comment: Post some code, bc it sounds like an issue on your side...

Comment: @Garrith you'll need to post some code and perhaps tell us what the character set is on your DB. But, as far as I know, MySQL does not automatically hex encode strings.

Comment: seriously this cant have stumped everyone?

Comment: Highly unlikely that MySQL is URL-encoding your strings. Try taking a look at the table contents with some other viewer (such as the command-line client) and see what's there.

Comment: yeah it is unlikely, checked with firebug and outputed what it says but im stumped can figure out why its doing that, ive changed the location to a folder within my visual studio website project works fine that way but when i pass it to run on nginx i have the feeling it will mess up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is `Image1.ImageUrl`. That definitely will URL encode the string that gets passed to it.

Comment: Test it. My preference is to not use Image controls at all. I would be more likely to use something like `<img src="<%= StringProperty %>" />' in my aspx file.